# Get firebase user id in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After register with Firebase phone number (sms), I can get `user_id` and friends list from `user_id`, etc. But after I exit from app, and then re-enter the app return null `(FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();)` I cannot not get Firebase `user id` (firebaseUser return null). `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'` Plz... How to solve a problem?

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) { // return null
    DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    reference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to login the user to the FirebaseAuth in order to persist in the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase automatically restores the user credentials when you restart the app. This requires it to make a call to the server, amongst others to check whether the account was disabled. Since this call may take some time to complete, most likely it's still ongoing when you call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`.

For this reason it's best to instead observe `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` as shown in the https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android. This callback gets called first when the authentication check I mentioned has completed, so you can use that to respond to the restored sign-in:

```
auth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            Log.i("firebase", "AuthState changed to null");
        }
        else {
            Log.i("firebase", "AuthState changed to "+firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: onCreate(), addAuthStateListener() return **AuthState changed to null**

Comment: So that means no user credentials were restored upon restart. Are you sure the user wasn't signed out before closing the app the previous time?

Comment: Yes, I login with phone number and then exit from app NOT Logout `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`. And enter the app, still Firebase user is null.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not immediately sure why that is. Can you update your question to also show how you used the code from my answer?

Comment: I create new project and test, it is OK return Firebase user. But in my current project return null LOL :D